# How can I style an elevated button?

Tags: flutter, button, styles

I want to give a background color for an elevated button in my flutter mini app. I tried using the buttonStyle attribute but I don't know what MaterialStateProperty is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these two methods. And for tour question you can use the first option.

```dart
   style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green)),
```

or

```dart
   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.amber),
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the style from property